# use AngularJS code in asp.net without MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, angularjs

I want to use AngularJS code in asp.net project without MVC architecture.
I used to insert a script after the closing tag of the body :

```
 <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
```

Then I tried to define the module to use expressions but I don't know how to include the necessary code to use in asp.net framework.

Comment: Why do you need server side framework at all to server the html?

Comment: I want to use the wide functions in angularJS instead of using Jquery in ,y application.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with using a server side framework. Most angular apps only require html files served. Can server them from a framework but generally easier to not even couple html with server code

Comment: sorry but the code doesn't work even if i use expressions in .html file!?

Comment: What type of expressions? Angular ones? Not making problem esy to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a basic example of using angular in asp.net web forms.You should ideally follow some sort of tutorial to learn angular.js.Have a look at [W3Schools Angular JS tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/) for example.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('app', []);

        app.controller('controller', function ($scope) {

            $scope.heading = "List Of Users:";

            $scope.users = [
            { id: 1, name: 'User 1' },
            { id: 2, name: 'User 2' },
            { id: 3, name: 'User 3' }]

            $scope.Clicked = function () {
                $scope.time = "Current time is - " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
            };

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <h1>{{heading}}</h1>
        <ul ng-repeat="u in users">
            <li>{{u.id + '-' + u.name}}</li>
        </ul>
        <input type="button" value="Click me" ng-click="Clicked()" />
        <div ng-bind="time">

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```